# How to separate business logic from an entity in Symfony

Tags: symfony, dto, business-logic

First of all I don't know if my title is clear and it is in fact they are not my words.

I work on a very "simple" project in my company: Build a Checkout with a few screens: Offers, Login, Register, Forgot password, User informations, Confirmation. We have 1 mouth.

We are 3 developers in this project. 2 juniors included me and 1 lead developer.

The lead developer said he wants to "separate business logic from entities". That "if we don't do it we will end up with a too big entity with the future needs, and the doctrine manager with it". But the User entity implements the Serializable interface and we only referring to user properties bypassing any Doctrine reference. He mention DTO a lot of time and I search for and not understand a particular thing.

So instead of creating the User entity the most classic way (doctrine mapping, validator assertions), he creates two classes.

A "model" User class that represent the user inputs with the validator annotations and, next pass the data to a service to call some setters on another User class that is an entity and then persist it.

Note that the "model" user class is NOT in the classic Entity namespace, and yes it does matter for the classic behavior of Symfony and Doctrine ORM to go pick annotation / mapping information and other stuff).

He asks me to write some unit test and functional test around user registration. After couple assertions I try to retrieve validator metadata to check if they are respected. To be more precise, validator errors messages.

But the evaluations of the UniqueEntity annotation don't work and indicate that the object manager can't be found for the object (Remember that he puts the assertions in the "Model" user and not the entity one), but indicate an "entityClass (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#entityclass)" value pointing to the entity one

I try to present facts and not including my judgement and toughs.

I think that I still can use the PropertyInfo Component to access the annotations, I will try tomorrow.

But what do you think of all this ? What do you think of this implementation ?

**To be sure that this question will not be marked as not pertinent to stackoverflow, I can ask: What's the best way to separate business logic from entities in Symfony project?**

Comment: I believe it is still too broad and requires opinion based answers.
At least ask separate question about unique entity validation.